# Trying to run a website using flask and ngrok on google colab and when i return render_template('layout.html'), the site have error

Tags: html, flask, google-colaboratory, ngrok, pyngrok

Basically, when i return "Hello", the website load fine but if i return render_templat('layout.html'), the site has error[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQr6G.png)
Here's the folder that houses these files[Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DQQv.png)
Here's the code

> ```
> from flask import Flask, render_template
> from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok
> !ngrok authtoken '--token--'
> # Webserver gateway interface
> app = Flask(__name__)
> run_with_ngrok(app)
> @app.route('/')
> def index():
>     return render_template('layout.html')
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     app.run()
> ```

i don't really understand it works so i haven't try anything. Hope anyone can help me